# Boats keep breaking in my canal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a canal that is 4 wide, and 1 block deep.  The entire canal is made of source blocks and completely level.  Unfortunately my boats keep breaking after only travelling a 50-60 blocks when I try to navigate the canal, and I don't really understand why.

Does my canal need to be deeper, wider?  What can I do to keep boats from breaking constantly?

[image: canal]

Comment: Are you hitting the side at all, or does it just break when you're in the middle?

Comment: (Edit) Woops, Nick T beat me to it...

Comment: That's odd; assuming there aren't any blocks jutting out and all of the water blocks are sources, it should be fine. Maybe upload your save or a video of you traveling through it?

Comment: I don't even bother with boats.  They seem pretty buggy right now.

Comment: @Kevin Y, The break even when I am in the middle.  I suspect, but have no confirmation, that it may have something to do with latency and SMP.

Comment: Ahh, SMP is probably to blame then. I tried setting up an [EATS Road](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19929/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-islands-together-in-minecraft/19993#19993) on an SMP server and the boats keep breaking as well.

Comment: Controlling the boats feels ... weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that you are on SMP so my guess is that you are lagging to the point where you bump into a wall.

A possible solution would to make the walls wider as boats are extremely fragile.

Boats are also pushed by water currents so it might keep the boat from bumping if you make water currents so I suggest that you make water flowing in the direction you want to travel rather than just creating still water everywhere.